# convert CSS filter brightness to PHP IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS

Tags: php, css, filter, gd

I have an image on my page with a **HTML** range slider below. When I move the slider, a bit of **jQuery** changes the **CSS** filter brightness of the image.

so I can for example get **CSS** to reduce the brightness by 10%, 20%, double the brightness to 200% etc. That works fine.

I want **PHP **(GD) to apply the brightness changes using `IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS`. The problem is `IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS` doesn't use percentages, it uses 0 for 100%, 255 for pure white and -255 for pure black.

Does anyone know how I can convert the value chosen on the slider to the corresponding value needed for **PHP**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the ranges correlate like so:

```
     | black | no change | white
-----|-------+-----------+-------
 CSS |     0 |         1 |     2
-----+-------+-----------+-------
 PHP |  -255 |         0 |   255
```

You can make a simple calculation in PHP:

```
$brightness = (255 - (255 * $css)) * -1;
```

Results:

- If `$css == 1` (100%) then `$brightness == 0`.
- If `$css == 0` (0%) then `$brightness == -255`.
- If `$css == .5` (50%) then `$brightness == -127.5`.
- If `$css == 1.2` (120%) then `$brightness == 51`.

Comment: @Gdev Did this answer your question?

Comment: Very late I know, sorry. Yes it did answer my question. Many thanks.

Comment: Better late than never! Thank you.